# Azure CosmosDB Cost of 1 Get is not 1 RU

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I am setting up a complex system with very high RU requirement, but trying to fine tune the query and indexes, but I could not figure out how to get RU = 1 for a single Get operation.

I created a single document in a test database as follows:

```
    {
        "id": "1",
        "key": "1",
    }
```

I set the consistency level to Eventual (which should have the lowest RU) I set no indexing and run this query:

```
SELECT * FROM c where c.id = "1" and c.key="1"
```

I always get Request Charge: 2.27 RUs. Am I doing something wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Try doing a read operation, instead of a query. You'll find a more efficient read.

Comment: Awesome, thanks David!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look at the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/request-units#a-request-unit-estimation-example), it differentiates a Read from a Query.

A Read uses ~1 RU, but a Query ~2.5 RU (which is similar to what you are seeing).

To Read (using the Id) you can use the [ReadDocumentAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.client.documentclient.readdocumentasync?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Documents_Client_DocumentClient_ReadDocumentAsync_System_Uri_Microsoft_Azure_Documents_Client_RequestOptions_) method in the SDK:

```
await yourDocDBSDKclient.ReadDocumentAsync(UriFactory.CreateDocumentUri(databaseName, collectionName, documentId));
```

There is also a section referring to [Considerations](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/request-units#request-unit-considerations) that might help in improving your RU usage.

Comment: Thanks Matias, I missed the part about query being different from a read, I thought it was the same thing. Newbie :)

Comment: There is no such a thing as a Newbie :) Never hesitate to ask :)

Comment: Hi Matias, Sorry to bug you again. I have found ReadDocumentAsync to be orders of magnitude slower than query, I think mostly due to 404s. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: I see, yes, there is a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-dotnet/issues/219) tracking exactly the thing you are mentioning. 404s tend to be slower in that case.